# Accidentally deleted performance counter on a performance monitor report

Tags: performancecounter, performance-monitor

On Performance Monitor, I was watching a Report of a test I had run, using a Custom Data Collector set. I use Highligh to see the counter I want, but I accidentally clicked on the button next to it, the Delete (Delete key) button, and that removed the counter from my report!
Is it possible to undo this action, and see it again on the graphic?

Comment: Re-run the report or go to the backup.

Comment: Do you mean running my test again and collecting the results gain? I wanted the results of the past test, unfortunatelly running again is not an option. Also, for the backup, what kind of backup are you refering to? Thanks

Comment: I always work on a copy of the original so I don't loose things like you have just done.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a way to put back the counter I deleted: right-click on the Report on the left handside and choose "Refresh".
Thanks anyway

Comment: Hello Joao, thank you to share with us your solution. The best way to do that is in the comments or just edit your own question.